# display multiple column records in one column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have Table having following columns in Oracle;

```
ID     NIC      NTN      MBL       NAME
---------------------------------------
1    1234512                       ABC
2               321                XYZ
3                         5421     POI
4    541245     624
```

I need to display like this in select query

```
ID   NIC/NTN/MBL      NAME
1    1234512          ABC
2    321              XYZ
3    5421             POI
4    541245                // taking first value
```

I was trying to do with

```
SELECT
A.ID,
"CNIC/NTN/MBL"
A.NAME,
A.REASON
B.NAME
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.R_ID = B.R_ID
 UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS
      (
        CNIC/NTN/MBL FOR cols IN (A.NIC, A.NTN, A.MBL)
      )
```

but unable to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    COALESCE(NIC, NTN, MBL) AS "NIC/NTN/MBL",
    NAME
FROM yourTable;
```

This should work because in the call to `COALESCE` above, I list the three columns from left to right, and the *first* non `NULL` value will be retained.

Answer (score 2):

You need the COALESCE function (which simply returns the first non-null value in the specified inputs, reading from left to right), like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 1234512 nic, NULL ntn, NULL mbl, 'ABC' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, NULL nic, 321 ntn, NULL mbl, 'ABC' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, NULL nic, NULL ntn, 5421 mbl, 'ABC' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 541245 nic, 624 ntn, NULL mbl, 'ABC' NAME FROM dual)
SELECT ID, 
       COALESCE(nic, ntn, mbl) nic_ntn_mbl,
       NAME
FROM   your_table;

        ID NIC_NTN_MBL NAME
---------- ----------- ----
         1     1234512 ABC
         2         321 ABC
         3        5421 ABC
         4      541245 ABC
```